# Issue with MergeMap with forkJoin Angular 5

Tags: angular, http, observable, rxjs5, fork-join

I am trying to execute 5 parallel http requests with mergeMap and forkJoin conditionally. For me only the first api is getting executed and rest of the apis are not triggering.

my function will execute first api and if it returns status as  'NOT_FOUND', then I need to execute another 5 apis and need to return the final result. If Iam getting status different from 'NOT_FOUND', need to just return the observable from first http request. I tried different options, but nothing seems to be working. Below shared code, Im getting  "ERROR TypeError: Unable to get property 'map' of undefined or null reference"

```
public myPostWrapper( url, body, flag): Observable<any> {
 return this.http.post( url, body, { headers: this.headers } )
        .map(( out: any ) => {
            console.log( 'out', JSON.stringify( out ) );
            this.result = out;
        } )
        .mergeMap(( response: any ) => {
            console.log( 'response-inside', JSON.stringify( response ) );
            if ( this.result.status === 'NOT_FOUND' ) {
                return Observable.forkJoin(
                    response.map(( resp: any ) => {
                        return this.http.post(url, body, { headers: this.headers })
                            .map(( res: any ) => {
                                const section: any = res;
                                return section;
                            } );
                    } ),
                    response.map(( resp: any ) => {
                        return this.http.post(url, body, { headers: this.headers })
                            .map(( res: any ) => {
                                const section: any = res;
                                return section;
                            } );
                    } )
                );
            } else {
                return Observable.of( this.result );
            }
        } )
        .catch(( error: any ) => Observable.throw( error || 'Server error' ) 
);
```

}

Any help/direction would be greately appreciated. Note Im using Rxjs 5.52 with Angular 5

Answer (score 2):

In the first `map`, where you set `this.result`, you don't return anything. That means, the following parts of the chain will operate on `undefined`. Add `return out;` to the first `map` operation, that should fix your issue.

```
...
return this.http.post( url, body, { headers: this.headers } )
    .map(( out: any ) => {
        console.log( 'out', JSON.stringify( out ) );
        this.result = out;
        return out; // <--- This return here
    } )
...
```

Optionally, you should replace all occurances of `response` in your `mergeMap` with `this.result`.

Comment: Thanks for quick help. That was one of the problem. I was not getting the response. But now ended up in another error - ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'map'. Also the second and third calls are not happening.

Comment: I have imported observable, map, mergeMap, of forkjoin from RxJs

Comment: If `response` is not an array, you can't `map` it.. `map` is an Array prototype method. (`[1,2,3].map(...)` will work, but `{a: [1,2,3]}.map` will not)

Comment: response is an array. If Iam executing the api calls individually, map works fine with the all the api used in this logic

Comment: You do `this.result.status`, where `this.result` is the same as `response` - that's a hint for me, that  `response` is a map of some kind, not an array...?